# Latex Item inline "Missing $ inserted." error

Tags: latex, pdflatex

Why does this line yield the "Missing $" error:

```
\begin{item} Hello \rightarrow \end{item}
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

try

```
\begin{item} Hello $\rightarrow$ \end{item}
```

Its a math symbol, so you have to use it in a math environment.

Comment: That's a good andwer, but I'd rather use `\begin{item} Hello \\(\rightarrow\\) \end{item}`. If you're not sure you are in math environment use `\ensuremath{\rightarrow}`.